# Log4j create a file for each logger

Tags: log4j

I have a lot of selenium tests that create a logger per class, it might not be the best way but it's code written by somebody else and I dont have time to rewrite it. I would like each Test of have it's own logfile so that it's easier to see what went wrong.

Is there a way to have log4j create a file for each logger that is created?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with log4j1 but I believe the only way is through programmatically adding the file appender to the logger.

Here is some sample code:

```
package test;

import org.apache.log4j.Appender;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;

public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
    private static final Logger logFoo = Logger.getLogger("test.Foo");
    private static final Logger logBar = Logger.getLogger("test.Bar");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.addAppender(createFileAppender("logs/main.log"));
        logFoo.addAppender(createFileAppender("logs/foo.log"));
        logBar.addAppender(createFileAppender("logs/bar.log"));

        logger.info("This is the main logger");
        logFoo.info("this is the foo logger");
        logBar.info("This is the bar logger");
    }

    private static Appender createFileAppender(String logName) {
        FileAppender fa = new FileAppender();
        fa.setName("FileLogger");
        fa.setFile(logName);
        fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
        fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        fa.setAppend(true);
        fa.activateOptions();
        return fa;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample log4j.xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="test" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

**Note** that you probably don't need to specify the console appender, I did it just to make sure things were working. You may not even need to specify any loggers, but I didn't test with that configuration.

The output of the above is 3 log files each containing the one message that was provided to the corresponding logger, and console output of all log messages.